# Pyspark. How to create df.shema like that one?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create schema like this:

```
root
 |-- _ehid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- request.id: string (nullable = true)
```

But i can create only that one:

```
root
 |-- _ehid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (nullable = true)
 |-- request.id: string (nullable = true)
```

I see struct type instead of array for element. And when i trying to look in my df by df.show(10), i see only nulls.

My script:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("_ehid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("duration", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("list", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("element", StringType())
        ])), True),
    StructField("request.id", StringType(), True)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `StringType` directly:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("_ehid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("duration", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("list", ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())), True),
    StructField("request.id", StringType(), True)])
```